# I want to make my custom tailwind classes use media prefixes

Tags: tailwind-css

I am building a website with tailwind as a css framework, but I ran into the problem that when I try to use the media query prefixes of tailwind (sm:, lg:, etc.) this error is thrown:

> `@apply` cannot be used with `.sm\:` because `.sm\:` either cannot be found, or its actual definition includes a pseudo-selector like :hover, :active, etc. If you're sure that `.sm\:` exists, make sure that any `@import` statements are being properly processed *before* Tailwind CSS sees your CSS, as `@apply` can only be used for classes in the same CSS tree.

Can someone explain how one should use these prefixes with own custom classes?
Thank you for your help already! <3

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the `@screen` directive to `@apply` style depending on the breakpoint.

See: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#screen

EDIT

You could normally declare it like so using a preprocessor or postcss-nested:

```
.your-class {
    @apply your-rules

    @screen sm {
        @apply your-rules-for-the-sm-breakpoint-and-above
    }

    @screen md  {
        @apply your-rules-for-the-md-breakpoint-and-above
    }
    /* etc... */
}
```

else use it this manner

```css
.your-class {
    @apply your-rules
}

@screen sm {
    .your-class {
        @apply your-rules-for-the-sm-breakpoint-and-above
    }
}

@screen md  {
    .your-class {
        @apply your-rules-for-the-md-breakpoint-and-above
    }
}
    /* etc... */
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: I get "@apply is not supported within nested at-rules like @screen" when trying this :/